# My pagination script is not working, its stuck at "Processing..."

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using this codes for my script in search module, I don't know what did I do wrong because last week it is still working. Can anyone help me fix this one?

These images shows the result from echo and print_r to keep track of the data that I am receiving.

this is my "echo $qString;" showing the response from my datepicker
[image]

and these 2 images shows the result of the search but it is not displaying on the webpage
[image]
[image]

here is the whole code for my model and script.

```
    function srch_gen048($data){

    $sEcho = intval($data["sEcho"]);
    $iDisplayStart = intval($data["iDisplayStart"]); //start of record
    $iDisplayLength = intval($data["iDisplayLength"]); //display size
    $pageNum = ($iDisplayStart/$iDisplayLength)+1; //page num
    $colSort = $data['iSortCol_0'];
    $dirSort = strtoupper($data['sSortDir_0']);


    $qString = "dbo.SEARCH_gen048 ";
    $qString .= "" . $colSort . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $dirSort . "',";
    $qString .= "" . $pageNum . ",";
    $qString .= "" . $iDisplayLength . ","; 
    $qString .= "" . $sEcho . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $data['sfDate'] . "'";

    //echo $qString;

    $this->db->query('set ansi_padding on
        set ARITHABORT on
        set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on
        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
        set ANSI_NULLS on
        set ANSI_WARNINGS on
        set numeric_roundabort off');

    $res = $this->db->query($qString);
    $res = $res->result();

    $iTotalDisplayRecords   = 0;
    $iTotalRecords          = 0;
    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        $iTotalDisplayRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //used for paging/numbering; same with iTotalRecords except if there will be search filtering
        $iTotalRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //total records unfiltered
    }

//print_r($res);

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($sEcho),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotalRecords,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iTotalDisplayRecords,
        "aaData" => array()

    );



    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        foreach($res as $row)
        {


                                $output['aaData'][] = array(
                                        $row->accnum,
                                        $row->accname,
                                        $row->add1,
                                        $row->accdate,
                                        $row->rmcode,
                                        $row->add4,
                                        $row->solcode,

                                        );

        }
    }


//print_r($output)

    return json_encode( $output );

}
```

and this is for my script, I think its working properly since the model and controller is the only codes that I've edited since the last time that it is working.

```
<script>



$(document).ready( function () {



    $('#acctable').dataTable({
                                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                "bAutoWidth": false,
                                "bFilter": false,
                                "bProcessing": true,
                                "bLengthChange": false,
                                "bServerSide": true,
                                "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/get_gen048",
                                "sServerMethod": "GET",
                                "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                                    aoData.push( { "name": "sfDate" , "value": "<?php echo $_POST["sfDate"] ?>" } );
                                        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {

                                        fnCallback(json);


                                    } );
                                },
                                "aoColumns": [
                                              { "sClass": "leftAligned" , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
                                              { "sClass": "rightAligned"    , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false }

                                              ]   

                            }); // oTable   

} );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No Need to Convert `output` array into `json_encode` format.

Try to change few modifications In controller

```
    foreach($res as $row)
    {
            $data['accnum']=$row->accnum;
            $data['accname']=$row->accname;
            $data['add1']=$row->add1;
            $data['accdate']=$row->accdate;

          $output['aaData'][] = $data;
    }


return $output;
```

and in your view script change like this.

`mData` property can be used to read data from any JSON data source property

```
    "aoColumns": [
   { "mData": "accnum","sClass": "leftAligned" , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
    { "mData": "accname","sClass": "leftAligned" , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
etc..
```

Thanks !

Comment: Sir, I am still experiencing the same problem, it is still stuck at "processing..." but when I echo/print out the the variables it contains the data but its just not showing on the table

Comment: Did you remove the `json_encode` while sending output?